# Start celery daemon via systemd

Tags: python, systemd

In the /usr/lib/systemd/system/celery.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Nodes Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/celery/main.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 /home/myuser/path/to/Django/myproject/manage.py celeryd_multi start w1 --pidfile="/var/run/celery/%n.pid" --logfile="/var/log/celery/%n.log" --cmd="-m celery.bin.celeryd_detach"
ExecStop=/usr/bin/python2 /home/myuser/path/to/Django/myproject/manage.py celeryd_multi stopwait w1 --pidfile="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

In the shell:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable celery.service
ln -s '/usr/lib/systemd/system/celery.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/celery.service'
$ sudo systemctl start celery.service
Job for celery.service failed. See 'systemctl status celery.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
$ sudo systemctl status celery.service
celery.service - Celery Nodes Daemon
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/celery.service; enabled)
  Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Пт 2013-03-29 13:22:24 NOVT; 38s ago
  Process: 32273 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 /home/anarchist/Desktop/Develop/Django/myproject/manage.py celeryd_multi start w1 --pidfile="/var/run/celery/%n.pid" --logfile="/var/log/celery/%n.log" --cmd="-m celery.bin.celeryd_detach" (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

In journalctl -xn nothing about celery. How to start the celery daemon via systemd?

Comment: i am very interested in this question, too

Comment: If this question is still relevant, you might try to put the ExecStart and ExecStop commands in separate shell scripts in /usr/local/bin

Comment: In the Arch /usr/bin

Answer (score 4):

After a whole bunch of experimenting i came up with this configuration for the service (modified to match your example):

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
KillMode=control-group
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 /home/myuser/path/to/Django/myproject/manage.py celeryd_multi start w1 --pidfile="/tmp/%n.pid" --logfile="/var/log/celery/%n.log" --loglevel=INFO --time-limit=300
ExecStop=/usr/bin/python2 /home/myuser/path/to/Django/myproject/manage.py celeryd_multi stopwait w1 --pidfile="/tmp/%n.pid"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Its final version I sent to the developer. We are waiting for new versions. If interested https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/1295

Comment: thanks for the hint. by the way if you think my answer has helped please consider upvoting and/or accepting it

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. I sent the developer my choice.

Comment: Please note that `After=network.target` is only intended for shutdown, not startup. If you want to wait for network configuration, you should use `Wants=network-online.target` and `After=network-online.target`.